# iOS7 SpriteKit how to reflect or mirror the entire game scene left-right?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, sprite-kit, skscene

I have an iPad game where the game flow is right to left - actors appear on right, looking towards left, then go towards left.

Now I'm trying to reflect the entire game, so everything is flipped - actors appear on left, look right, go right.

**How can I achieve such mirror/reflect effect for the entire game without having to rewrite all coordinates and having to reflect each actor?**

I tried this, but it does not seem to work:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        self.xScale = -1;

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be: "actors appear on left, look right, go right."..?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing that. There are numerous reported issues with using xScale = -1; Mainly to do with physics bodies. An object's physics body no longer responds to contacts and collisions after this command and thereby causing it to drop off the screen (if gravity is on).

Unfortunately, for this release of Sprite Kit, you have no other option but to rewrite your code.

Comment: The scale property is a purely visual property and doesn't affect physics at all. The physics continue to work as usual but the node(s) with xScale -1 are visually offset from their physics bodies. What you then observe as the physics no longer working is actually the visuals no longer matching up with the physics world.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - Thank you for putting it more eloquently than me. Bottom line though, it causes problems.